# How to change the content of access tokens created through Keycloak token exchange

Tags: keycloak, token-exchange

My goal is it to get two resource server specific access tokens which contains only the data specific to the respective resource server.

I have the following setup: a public client is using 2 resource servers.

After configuring *clients*, *users*, *realm roles*, *client scopes* and by using the *scope* parameter, I am able to create 2 different, resource server specific access tokens:

```
{
  "exp": 1603234566,
  "iat": 1603216566,
  "jti": "13ae00ac-ce57-43ce-8b47-39ad6d5445cd",
  "iss": "http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/fitness-realm",
  "aud": "fitness-resource-server-1",
  "sub": "de1f0820-f4d9-49be-a6d1-c8faef083ffc",
  "typ": "Bearer",
  "azp": "fitness-client",
  "session_state": "47ea42f9-42ac-452e-9e54-be6d705e9a61",
  "acr": "1",
  "realm_access": {
    "roles": [
      "fitness_user"
    ]
  },
  "scope": "openid email profile client_scope_fitness_resource_server_1_roles",
  "email_verified": false,
  "preferred_username": "bill"
}
```

and

```
{
  "exp": 1603235280,
  "iat": 1603217280,
  "jti": "fb75a956-6ed4-4edd-8e20-2cd9678d4869",
  "iss": "http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/fitness-realm",
  "aud": "fitness-resource-server-2",
  "sub": "de1f0820-f4d9-49be-a6d1-c8faef083ffc",
  "typ": "Bearer",
  "azp": "fitness-client",
  "session_state": "966aa651-0534-43d4-9413-a8c141ee8549",
  "acr": "1",
  "realm_access": {
    "roles": [
      "fitness_user"
    ]
  },
  "scope": "openid email profile client_scope_fitness_resource_server_2_roles",
  "email_verified": false,
  "preferred_username": "bill"
}
```

During the login process I set the *scope* parameter to *client_scope_fitness_resource_server_1_roles* and get the first, resource server 1 specific access token. Since I get only one access token during the login process and my client is public, I want to use the resource server 1 to get the 2nd - resource server 2 specific - access token by using Keycloak’s internal token to internal token *token exchange* feature. I followed the instructions and I’am able to get the second token with this call:

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/fitness-realm/protocol/openid-connect/token \
    -d "client_id=fitness-resource-server-1” \
    -d "client_secret=<my_secret>" \
    -d "grant_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:token-exchange" \ 
    -d "subject_token=$FIRST_ACCESS_TOKEN" \
    -d "requested_token_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:token-type:refresh_token" \
    -d "audience=fitness-resource-server-2" |jq
```

But if I look inside of the second token it contains more informations I want:

```
{
  "exp": 1603234572,
  "iat": 1603216572,
  "jti": "4f4b0fb6-d759-4c6a-b35d-7e2a998b5a20",
  "iss": "http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/fitness-realm",
  "aud": [
    "other_resource_server",
    "fitness-client",
    "other_client",
    "account",
    "fitness-resource-server-2"
  ],
  "sub": "de1f0820-f4d9-49be-a6d1-c8faef083ffc",
  "typ": "Bearer",
  "azp": "fitness-resource-server-1",
  "session_state": "47ea42f9-42ac-452e-9e54-be6d705e9a61",
  "acr": "1",
  "realm_access": {
    "roles": [
      "fitness_user",
      "offline_access",
      "uma_authorization"
    ]
  },
  "scope": "email profile",
  "email_verified": false,
  "preferred_username": "bill"
}
```

My question is, how can I configure Keycloak that the second access token did not contain the roles "offline_access" and "uma_authorization" and the aud: "other_resource_server", "fitness-client", "other_client", "account”?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution :-)

I have to change the resource server 2 *settings* - *access type* configuration from *bearer only* to *confidential*, disable all flows/grants, and with this change I am able to configure the *Client Scope* and *Scope* in the resource server 2 too.

It is not so nice that I have to change from *bearer only* to *confidential* even because I don't need *confidential* (flows/grants, credentials, etc.) but this makes it possible to change the access token output.